# Return com todas as linhas do foreach

Tags: php, array, foreach

eu tenho o seguinte [script](http://pastebin.com/zYUSg7eU):

```
<?php
$recursos_data = array(
        array(
                "id" => "0",
                "recurso_nome" => "madeira",
                "producao" => "%produz%",
                "estoque" => "200"
        ),
        array(
                "id" => "1",
                "recurso_nome" => "comida",
                "producao" => "%produz%",
                "estoque" => "100"
        )
);
foreach($recursos_data as $recurso):
        $retornar = preg_replace("/%produz%/", '500', $recursos_data[$recurso['id']]);
endforeach;
return $retornar

?>
```

eu quero dar um return, que no `print_r`, retorne todas as linhas do array.

quando eu dou um print_r dentro do foreach, ele mostra todas as linhas do array exemplo:

```
Array ( [id] => 0
        [recurso_nome] => madeira
        [producao] => 500
        [estoque] => 200 )
        Array ( [id] => 1 
                [recurso_nome] => comida
                [producao] => 500
                [estoque] => 100
        )
```

e se eu dou um `print_r` fora do foreach, só imprime a ultima linha do array e também não faz a conversão do %produz%:

```
Array ( [id] => 1
        [recurso_nome] => comida
        [producao] => %produz%
        [estoque] => 100
)
```

depois de pesquisar muito, descobri que você pode adicionar resultados usando `.=` só que eu sempre recebo um erro algo como "você não pode transformar array em string"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para criar/retornar um novo array contendo as substiuições de `%produz%` são necessario dois passos:

1- Defina o novo array antes do foreach.

2 - Use colchetes `[]` para dizer que a modificação será feita em novo item/linha.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($recursos_data as $recurso):
        $arr[] = preg_replace("/%produz%/", '500', $recursos_data[$recurso['id']]);
endforeach;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qvta-migz)**

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode reorganizar seu código dessa forma:

```
<?php
$recursos_data = array(
        array(
                "id" => "0",
                "recurso_nome" => "madeira",
                "producao" => "%produz%",
                "estoque" => "200"
        ),
        array(
                "id" => "1",
                "recurso_nome" => "comida",
                "producao" => "%produz%",
                "estoque" => "100"
        )
);

$lista_retornar = array();
foreach($recursos_data as $recurso):
        array_push($lista_retornar, preg_replace("/%produz%/", '500',     $recursos_data[$recurso['id']]));
endforeach;

print_r($lista_retornar);

?>
```